# Change Default Contact Manager to My own

Tags: android

I writing a contact manager for android and I want to know how can I change default contact manager to my own program?

Comment: That's up to the user. When they have more then one app that do the same thing a Dialog will show up letting them pick one and let them set it as the default if they wish.
You can try it by installing two apps that do the same thing, two launchers for example, or media players.

Comment: I mean Contacts manager not Dialer like viber.

Comment: It still applies. The user can set the default and they will get a choice but you as the developer cannot force them to use your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't alter the default apps yourself for security reasons. The user must manually choose you as the default for certain actions when the chooser dialog comes up.

This is for security reasons, as if it were allowed without user intervention any malicious app could make itself the default for any action is wanted.

Comment: you said manually choose. where is it? and how can I add my application to that list?

Comment: Your app registers for certain events, like a launcher does for the home button, or a camera app for the camera intent. When more than one app can handle an event, a dialog box comes up, and the user must select from there. You can see this in action by trying to share a photo from the gallery. Ideally, you'll get a dialog box asking you to choose between facebook, gmail, sms etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. can you show me how can I register my app for difference place?

Comment: @OmidMafakher That depends entirely on what your app does, and you require a different intent filter for different types of actions. Read up on Intents and Intent filters and see which options are needed for your app